# Button on-click expands over other elements to reveal longer string of text

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I am attempting to do some JS animation, but failing miserably.

Essentially I have 3 links placed next to each other.
The first two are simply links that open in a new window.
The third button when clicked needs to slide out to the left, and overlay it's neighbours, revealing a `span` which is hidden by default (a URL).

I've set up a basic codepen example:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EsojF

The idea is that the third button when pressed will fill the width of the entire UL, sitting on top of the other links or they could slide away to zero width and the URL inside the `span` should be then displayed (ideally the link would also copy to clipboard but not yet even considered that route).

Can anyone offer any pointers?
My client has a number of users still using IE9 so I believe javascript or jquery to be the best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit, Updated

Try (v2)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('.get-url a').click(function (e) {
        // cache selector
        var elem = jQuery(this);
        // `elem` parent sibling `li` elements
        var parents = elem.parent("li").siblings();
        // set `width` of `elem` parent `li`
        var width = parseInt(elem.parents("ul").css("width")) * .6;
        // toggle `parents` ,
        // set `width` of `elem` parent `li`
        // toggle `url-reveal` `span`
      if (elem.find(".url-reveal").css("display") === "none") {  
               // added minimal slide effect         
               parents.toggle(-1000).promise()
               .done(elem.children('span').toggle(200)                              
               , elem.parent("li").animate({width: width }, -200));
        } else {
               // reverse toggle
               parents.toggle(-1000).promise()
               .done(elem.children('span').toggle(-2000, "linear")
                 , elem.parent("li").animate({width: "100"}, -1000, "linear"))           
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('.get-url a').click(function (e) {
        // cache selector
        var elem = jQuery(this);
        // `elem` parent sibling `li` elements
        var parents = elem.parent("li").siblings();
        // set `width` of `elem` parent `li`
        var width = parseInt(elem.parents("ul").css("width")) * .6;
        // toggle `parents` ,
        // set `width` of `elem` parent `li`
        // toggle `url-reveal` `span`
      if (elem.find(".url-reveal").css("display") === "none") {
        
               parents.toggle(-1000).promise()
               .done(elem.children('span').toggle(200)                              
               , elem.parent("li").animate({width: width }, -200));
        } else {
               parents.toggle(-1000).promise()
               .done(elem.children('span').toggle(-2000, "linear")
                 , elem.parent("li").animate({width: "100"}, -1000, "linear"))            
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

```css
.url-reveal {
    display: none;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 450px;
}
ul li {
    width: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #c50000;
    margin: 0;
}
ul li a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com">Facebook</a>
    </li>
    <li class="get-url"><a href="#"><span class="label">Get URL</span> <span class="url-reveal">http://www.longURLGoeshere.com</span></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is close to what I was after. I'd need to add some sort of slide out effect as the URL moves over the other two links, and it should revert to the standard size if clicked again... will have a look.

Comment: Thanks this was a great basis for me to build on.

Answer (score 1):

If you remember the by making something relative you can move it's position on the screen without moving it in the DOM, then remembering that by default overflow is visible you can work out the parents offset and make the span grow outside of it's parent.

I have amended your codepen to make it work: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Czwlk

However my real answer would be to recode and take another viewpoint, instead of making the link grow why don't you cover all three links with a new temporary link:

```
jQuery('<span>Long Url</span>').insertAfter(this);
```

Assuming you aren't injecting a link but rather a plain text url for the user to manually share with.

Answer 2!

The way I would code it is as follows. Firstly I would set the parent UL to display inline-block so it wraps the links tightly, and then give it position relative. Then when the link is clicked I inject an input field into after the link with position absolute - this way I can make it fill the UL and completely cover all the links. As you can see for extra sugar I also focus and select the input so the user can copy and paste it where they want. All you would need to finish the code is decide how you want to close the tooltip afterwards. The easiest way would be to add a close icon to the tooltip which .remove() the tooltip on click. As it doesn't affect the link it would still work and inject a new div if required.

Demo here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dkGAy

Full animated demo here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/iFmeu

Comment: Thanks for the answer - the codepen seems to be the original, did you save your suggestions?

It is indeed just a link to be copied & shared manually. The main requirement is to make it look like a nice slide out animation as the button grows.

Comment: @steve fixed the links and added a better solution

Comment: Thanks so much for this - I actually implemented an earlier answer already, but I've upvoted and really appreciate your efforts.